# Cordova App rate aligning buttons vertically

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap with the [app rate plugin](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate). I'm calling:

`AppRate.promptForRating(true)`;

and I'm getting all buttons in a single line.

There are 3 buttons, and in many devices button's text is truncated.

Comment: Your view is Landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an [open issue of the plugin](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/63). Add your case to the open issue on github.

If you can solve this issue by your own, send a pull request to the author.